# Is it possible to concat a JS variable into the PHP mail method, if so, how?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I'm trying to send an email using the PHP mail function, but the required content is stored in a JS variable, I'll try to code out my situation for you to understand better.

```
<script type="txt/js">
var content = "This is what I need to send via email";
 if({Irrelevant validation check})
{
 alert("Form submitted! Redirecting... <?PHP mail('admin@admin.com', 'subject', [XXX]);?>");
}
</script>
```

I need the text stored in the content variable to be in place of the [XXX] above.

I would appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Have you tried placing 'echo' before 'mail...'?

Comment: @killQuotes I don't understand why that would be necessary. That function is working silenty which is what I want, why would I echo it out?

Comment: Use Ajax. Send the data via Ajax to a PHP script that will send the email.

Comment: oh ok, the answer about using an ajax call would be your best option then.

Comment: @killQuotes I guess so.

Comment: This is a big no no, as spamers would love your site , so unless you make PHP part very secure, ie you must be certain 100% that ajax call is coming from your site. Your code above will always send mail. As Pierre mentioned you need ajax call see @meda answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way simpler using `$.post()`:

```
$.post("sendEmail.php", { contentData: content },  function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  //Form submitted! ...Redirecting... 
});
```

**sendEmail.php**

```
$content = $_POST['contentData'];

$to = 'someemail@domain.com';
$subject = 'The content';
$message = 'Content'.$content;
$headers = 'From: youremail@domain.com' . "\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){ 
    echo "Your email was sent!"; 
}else{
    echo "Email did not send";
}
```

Comment: Despite the way I asked my question, this seems to be the only person who understood exactly what I needed, and though this won't work for some reason (not receiving the email), it's the closest answer and I will therefore mark it as the best.

Comment: All you wanted was someone to write the whole code for you.

Comment: @harsh.prasad Everyone has a different level of understanding people. Just because yours wasn't as good as this one, doesn't mean I don't appreciate your answer - this one was just particularly more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned it, using AJAX is your best option. You can pass the information to the php file using AJAX as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : content,
    success : alert('success'),
    error: alert('error')
});
```

To have better data handling, you can define a Formdata and save the content var in that data.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("content", content);
```

and then you can post this data:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : data,
        success : alert('success'),
        error: alert('error')
    });
```

Comment: I've seen this before, but I have no idea how it's used. I'm assuming a form is needed or the POST data to be transferred? Well I'm not using a form in this case, I just need a variable transferred.

Comment: No you don't need a form, you can just use this code in the place where you are calling your alert function. And then you can handle this data in the php file.

Comment: I'm really not that experienced with this :( Could you pls be more specific... how would the PHP file look like when you say 'handle'

Comment: Well, i would strongly suggest to look at some tutorial about how to handle post requests in php. For starters: 
http://thephpbasics.com/tutorial-21-get-post-return/

Comment: In the answer posted above, just change the url to the name of the php file, and in the tutorial you can see how a sample php file would look like and in the php file you can access the data field as $_POST['data']. Try some simple post requests so that you become comfortable in php.

Comment: I know how post/get are handled in PHP >.<, I just thought forms were required for them.

Comment: Lol, no.. Forms are not necessary. Forms just provide you inherited accessibility to post. But using ajax you can definitely simulate the actions.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use pure javascript to do ANYTHING that affects the PHP *code*. PHP is run on the server side. Javascript is run on the client side. However if you set up your php as a service, i.e. in PHP set up page X to accept mail information, and then use javascript to post to page X, page X will effectively send the mailing with the info given to it by javascript. But javascript cannot directly affect PHP code.

PHP Code is rendered first, Then HTML, Then Javascript. It's the web stack.

AJAX can be used to talk back and forth between client and server like the other answers are mentioning, but the question was is it possible and how do you use JS to send mail via PHP.

Comment: Really? What if I stored it in a global variable that I then read using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I simply used the window.open(url.php?var=var); method using Javascript, and passed the variable through the GET parameter, then the "url.php" page picked it up via $_GET['var'];

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use AJAX in this kind of situations. Pass the "var content" value via AJAX and do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  now how could I apply this exactly?

Comment: If you are using jQuery then you can easily implement this. Here is an example of ajax POST

    $.post( "test.php", { email: "admin@admin.com", subject: "subject", content: "content" } );

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-ajax-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-methods-with-examples/

Comment: could you tell me what the 'test.php' will look like please?